# stacklist implementation

Tags: c++, linked-list

following  linked list  implementation with stacks  works fine

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
   class Link
   {
   public:
       long ddata;
       Link *next;
       Link(long d){
        ddata=d;

       }
        void displaylink(){
         cout<<ddata<<"  "<<endl;

        }



   };
   class LinkedList{
   private :

    Link * first;
   public:
       LinkedList(){
        first=NULL;

       }


       bool empthy(){

        return first==NULL;
       }
       void insertfirst(long dd){
        Link *newlink=new Link(dd);
        newlink->next=first;
        first=newlink;

       }
       long deletefirst(){

        Link *temp=first;
        first=first->next;
        return temp->ddata;


       }
        void display(){

         Link *current=first;
         while(current!=NULL){
             current->displaylink();
             current=current->next;

         }

          cout<<endl;
        }


   };



   class StackList{
   public:
     LinkedList *ls;
   public:
       StackList(){
           ls=new LinkedList();

       }
         void push(long j){
             ls->insertfirst(j);

         }
            long pop(){
                return   ls->deletefirst();

            }

            bool empthy()
            {
                return (ls->empthy());
            }
                void displaystack(){
                    ls->display();


                }



   };
int main(){


     StackList *SL=new StackList();
     SL->push(20);
     SL->push(40);
     SL->push(60);
     SL->displaystack();
     SL->pop();
     SL->displaystack();


 return 0;
}
```

but i am interested  if it has some possible bugs or  can it be optimized more?if you see some nonsecury point in this code please tell me how to correct it?thanks a lot,it is just curiosity question

Comment: Might be more on topic at [Stack Exchange Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Why didn't you apply some of the memory management changes suggested in answers to your earlier question?

Comment: i thought  using stack and list  there  should be another  steps for  memory managment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your memory management is flawed - as is, it will leak because there are `new`s but no `delete`s. Once you take care of the `delete`s, make sure you handle copies of the classes (have the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) in mind).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Link
{
public:
    long ddata;
    Link *next;
    Link(long d)
    {
        ddata=d;
    }
    void displaylink()
    {
        cout<<ddata<<"  "<<endl;
    }
};

class LinkedList
{
private :
    Link * first;

public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        first=NULL;
    }

    ~LinkedList()//do not forget to delete objects
    {
        Link *current = first;
        while(current!=NULL)
        {
            delete current;
        }
        first = NULL;
    }

    bool empthy()
    {
        return first==NULL;
    }

    void insertfirst(long dd)
    {
        Link *newlink=new Link(dd);
        newlink->next=first;
        first=newlink;
    }

    long deletefirst()
    {
        Link *temp=first;
        first=first->next;//notice, first may be NULL!
        return temp->ddata;
    }

    void display()
    {
        Link *current=first;
        while(current!=NULL)
        {
            current->displaylink();
            current=current->next;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
};

class StackList
{
public:
    LinkedList *ls;

public:
    StackList()
    {
        ls=new LinkedList();
    }

    ~StackList()//do not forget 
    {
        delete ls;
        ls = NULL;  
    }

    void push(long j)
    {
        ls->insertfirst(j);
    }

    long pop()
    {
        return   ls->deletefirst();
    }

    bool empthy()
    {
        return (ls->empthy());
    }

    void displaystack()
    {
        ls->display();
    }
};

int main()
{
    StackList *SL = new StackList();
    SL->push(20);
    SL->push(40);
    SL->push(60);
    SL->displaystack();
    SL->pop();
    SL->displaystack();
    delete SL;//it's good manners to do so
    SL = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```